# How to compress files based on a file date

Tags: shell, files, zip

I have a min 30 files in a directory which contains older dates  I.e for past 7 days . Now I need to compress them based on its file creation/modified date.

For example,
10 files with April 7 -- create a zip for april7.zip
10 files with April 8 -- create a zip for april8.zip
10 files with April 9 -- create a zip for april9.zip

Comment: look at the find command. options -ctime or -atime. Maybe -depth 1 Use with -exec

Comment: What rule do you have to determine the April 7 files? Modification time between April 7 midnight and April 7 23:59:59 ?

Comment: By using find with mtime option will help us determine the file dates.

Answer (score 4):

The usual `find -mtime` is a bit hard to use here, since it only tests age relative to current point in time.

With GNU date and Bash we could do something like this to add each file to an archive corresponding to the file's date:

```
for f in * ; do 
    zip $(date -r "$f" +%F).zip "$f"        # 2017-04-07.zip
done
```

or:

```
for f in * ; do
    d=$(date -r "$f" +%B%d)
    zip ${d,,}.zip "$f"                     # april07.zip
done                                        # ${var,,} is for lowercase
```

(`date` can only read the modification time. For `ctime` we'd need to use `stat` and do more work to fix the output format.)

---

If, for some reason, we need to get a list of all the files for a certain date before processing, we could collect them to an array:

```
files=()
date="2017-04-07"
for f in * ; do 
    [ "$(date -r "$f" +%F)" = "$date" ] && files+=("$f")
done
# do something with "${files[@]}', e.g.
# zip $date.zip "${files[@]}"
```

As such, this would only handle a single given date at a time.